# integrated security vs. password in code - small .net app with some SQL writing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, security, credentials

I have a small app that changes some values in our MS SQL DB. The app is used by a handfull of people daily.

Is it better to give all these people db_datawriter in the SQL Server and use the integrated security in the app?

Or should I create SQL user just for this app and store the credentials in the code?

Or is there a better solution/best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't allow such access to the DB if I were the Admin. I'd prefer a Service talk to the DB and the Clients talk to the Service.

Comment: @Fildor: and then, the service wouldn't have the credentials hard-coded, but configured by the admin.

Comment: @ThomasWeller for example. If it runs on azure, the key vault would also be an option.

Comment: This seems like an excellent time for OP to implement an API server to do the database accessing

Comment: it is all on premise and a very small - but usefull- app. :-)
to add a service is for sure the way to go, thanks ... but for now a bit of an overkill.
untill i get there, do you have a answer to the first part of my question? or are both ways absolute no-gos?

Comment: Kind of opinionated. I'd personally cringe hard, if I had to hard code credentials even if it is just a "very small, internal use, only" app.

Comment: Integrated security, because sql server authentication requires a password, and the client app with a password that can be read or decompiled is a no-go IMHO. If there are too many users you can create a windows group and assign the integrated security to that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few years ago my response would have been if it is just small internal app, create a sql user and store the credentials in the app config...

**However** coming from experience '*just a small app*' has the tendency to grow with functionality as the business realises that more value can be added to this '*quick win*' '*small app*'.

Spend a little time and **do it properly** by creating an app that communicates with an API.

You **will be** grateful later on that you started of with the correct approach and it also solidifies best practice and good design. You could also do it properly now, set up a **core application** that can be duplicated or used when creating other apps.

If you ***really insist*** on not using an API there really is no good answer to you question in regards to ***best practice***

Creating users in the database is an admin nightmare, but it does leave security to the OS.
Saving credentials in code/config and using a SQL user is easier to administrate, but code can be decompiled, exposing your password.

Comment: "_Creating users in the database is an admin nightmare_" you can create individual logins for each users, but is far easier to manage adding a login to a windows (domain) group and adding or removing users from that group

Comment: @bradbury9 I agree it is far easier with a domain group however it is still a bigger overhead than giving access to an app via domain policies and letting the API do its thing.

Comment: Indeed, my go-to order would be: 1- API. 2- integrated security (using groups) 3- SQL Server user/password

Comment: thanks a lot ... i added the integrated security for now and will go for the API very soon!